# Recover input values with purrr possibly

Tags: r, purrr

I would like to have a workaround for the following situation: every time the operation fails, I want purrr to return the input values. The code below illustrates what I want.

```
library(purrr)

id<-c(1:6)

value<-c(rnorm(5),NA)

df<-data.frame(id,value)

map2_dfr(df$id,df$value,possibly(~{
z<-.y*2
data.frame(.x,.y,z)
 },
data.frame(.x,.y,NA)
)
)
```

> `Error in data.frame(.x, .y, NA) : object '.x' not found`

Comment: Two quick comments here: 

1. What is insufficient about the default behavior here? Your `.y` column has an `NA` at row 6, and your `z` column also has an `NA` at row 6. You can clearly see the `NA` input led to the `NA` output.

2. Why use a loop at all? Why not specify this problem as `df$z <- df$value * 2`

Comment: The real case is a web scraping. I need to loop through multiple links. Actually, I want to recover only the id(links) so I will know which requests failed. Apparently, your comment gave me the answer. I just have to put `data.frame(df$id,df$value,NA)`

Comment: I think that the `otherwise` parameter from `possibly()` accepts only hard coded values. It wont see the arguments from the function passed to `.f`